# jquery loop through anchors to match class of hovered anchor and apply css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="week start-available start-mid end-available end-mid overlap-False">


                <a href="http://alink.com" class="20130906-20130912">
                    <span class="wk-start" style="">    

                            <span class="day overlap-False">9 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">10 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">11 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">12 </span>

                    </span>
                </a>



                <a href="http://alink.com" class="20130913-20130919">
                    <span class="wk-end">

                            <span class="day overlap-False">13 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">14 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">15 </span>

                    </span> 
                </a> 


            </div>
<div class="week start-available start-mid end-available end-mid overlap-False">


                <a href="http://alink.com" class="20130913-20130919">
                    <span class="wk-start" style="">    

                            <span class="day overlap-False">16 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">17 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">18 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">19 </span>

                    </span>
                </a>



                <a href="http://alink.com" class="20130920-20130926">
                    <span class="wk-end">

                            <span class="day overlap-False">20 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">21 </span>


                            <span class="day overlap-False">22 </span>

                    </span> 
                </a> 


            </div>
```

I would like to use jquery to apply css to an anchor with the same class of the anchor currently hovered. Every anchor has another with the same class but belongs to a different parent.

I'm assuming I need to loop through all the elements to match the class of the one hovered but must admit i'm a bit lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: refresh question with short markup what actually you need.

Comment: A bit confused... when you hover on an anchor do you want to highlight the other anchors with *all* the same classes or any anchor with any *one* of the classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $as = $('.week > a').hover(function(){
    $as.not(this).filter('.' + this.className).addClass('test')
}, function(){
    $as.not(this).filter('.' + this.className).removeClass('test')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cb9An/)